# Hook save_post not working with custom post type

Tags: wordpress, hook

I have problems to use a hook after a custom post type post (created with "Toolset Types" plugin), post is saved in WP backend.

As a simple example I tried this code:

```
function test123($post_id){
   file_put_contents('test.log',' TEST'."\n",FILE_APPEND);
}
add_action('save_post','test123');
```

If I save a standard wordpress post, everything works fine and the log is written but if I save a post of my custom post type the log isn't written. Also tried it with the hook "wp_after_insert_post", but it didn't work either...

It does't make sense to me, why this isn't working. Does anybody have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Try `add_action('save_post','test123');`

Comment: @MosheGross Sorry, it was a mistake while writing this post, of course I tried it with "save_post".

Answer (score 1):

The `save_post` hook only fires for WordPress' default post and page types. You'll need to use a custom hook (`save_post_<post_type_slug>`) for your custom post type, based on its slug/registered name.

If your custom post type is something like `property_listing`, then you'll need to call `save_post_property_listing`, like so:

```php
add_action('save_post_property_listing', 'test123');
```

More info on the [Wordress Developer Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The slug of my post typ is "pt_projektpartner" so I tried it with add_action('save_post_pt_projektpartner','test123') but it doesn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: @Christian Hmm, should be working. I haven't used the Toolset Types plugin before, so maybe the name of the post type is slightly different? If you pop add_action( 'init', function() {var_dump(get_post_types());}); into your code (functions.php), then it should show all the post types on your site, including the pt_projektpartner if that's the same name as its declared to be. If its the same, I'll see what else might be causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Obviously Toolset Types behaves different...I created two custom post types in my project and none of them is listet in the var_dump of the "get_post_types"...strange...but now I know that's the reason why the add_action doesn't work... To be honest, in the meantime I had another idea to bypass my problem, so I don't need a solution for this anymore... Thanks for taking the time trying to help me!

Comment: The hook just calls the function at a certain point in time - Toolset Types might be creating the custom post types after the init hook is called (so at that point the post types weren't crated). But no worries!